# timeIntervalSinceDate returns the wrong value

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have two functions.
The first is writing NSDate() to NSUserDefaults as a string.

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSxxx"
let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(dateString, forKey: "lastDate")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

The second one is reading this value, converting it to NSDate and comparing with the current time and date.

```
let dateString = try NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("lastDate")
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSxxx"

if dateString != nil {
    let date = try dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString!)

    if date != nil {
        let interval = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(date!)
        let interval2 = Int(interval)
        print(interval2)
    }
} else {
    //some code here        
}
```

The thing is, it returns not 5 seconds (as it should, for example) but something like 43295 or 44592. I logged dates and strings and they seemed fine. Where did I break things?

Comment: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSxxx"  h is for 1-12h

Comment: it helped. thank you very much!

Comment: You don't need to convert to/from strings here, you can save `NSDate` to user defaults without changing it.